# how to write a complex query in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem.Let's say I have two tables one is `sol_items` another is `sol_informations`.
Now `sol_items` has many associated records in `sol_informations` table.
I would like to get the latest `sol_informations` associated records of every 'sol_items' using a single query.

so let's say I have 3 records in `sol_items` table each of this records has 3 associated records in `sol_informations`.
Now I want the exactly the latest record from thesol_informationstable for each of the `sol_items` associated with `sol_informations`.

I have tried below

```
select * from solbox_informations where(sol_item_id in (1,2,3) ) LIMIT 1
```

But this only returns one record for the first element of the `sol_items`table.
You can't increase LIMIT value.

Can someone help me out with the proper query.

`sol_items` table columns

```
id, name
```

`sol_informaitons` table columns

```
id, name, amount, sol_item_id
```

Comment: you are looking for a join I think. please disclose tables structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a subquery.

```
SolInformaiton.where(id: SolInformaiton.group(:sol_item_id).maximum(:id).values)
```

**Explanation:**

```
ids = SolInformaiton.group(:sol_item_id).maximum(:id).values
```

will group all records in `SolInformaiton` by `sol_item_id` and select 1 record from each group having maximum value of id (the latest). It will return `ActiveSupport::OrderedHash` with `sole_item_id` as key and `id` as value, thus `.values` will return array of required IDs.

```
SolInformaiton.where(id: ids)
```

It is a simple where query which will return records with ids in array.

Comment: can you please explain this query?

Comment: Thanks man for this answer with great explanation.I've accepted your answer.